# Rails App Not Working In Heroku Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently changed my Rails app database from sqlite3 to postgresql. The app works fine in development on C9, but I'm running into problems with Heroku production. On Heroku, the index page actually displays, but navigating to the sign up page or trying to log in produces this error on the page:

*We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.*

I've done a bit of searching and have found that I'm supposed to run `$ heroku run rails db:migrate` in order for my app to work. However, when attempting to migrate, I am told that I need to start the server. After running `$ rails s` and then attempting the migration, I get this error in the terminal:

*Cannot run more than 1 Free size dynos.*

I have already attempted `heroku ps:stop worker` and `heroku ps:stop <DYNO>`, but both return this error in the terminal:

*Expected response to be successful, got 400*

Edit: There are the error logs I get when navigating to the sign up page:

```
2017-08-16T01:17:58.770873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No 
web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=operation-give-
back.herokuapp.com request_id=484539c6-91dd-42da-863c-e293f008d2c1 
fwd="75.171.228.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-08-16T01:18:00.108900+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No 
web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=operation-give-
back.herokuapp.com request_id=de8eff7f-4e1c-4fe0-8a99-ba731109d8de 
fwd="75.171.228.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-08-16T01:18:00.206753+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No 
web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=operation-give-
back.herokuapp.com request_id=a6d18caf-0c2e-44bb-aa09-cf4c0141054d 
fwd="75.171.228.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-08-16T01:18:01.101111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No 
web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=operation-give-
back.herokuapp.com request_id=c71d4340-17d7-4bcf-b50d-20aeee5494d4 
fwd="75.171.228.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-08-16T01:18:01.002590+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No 
web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=operation-give-
back.herokuapp.com request_id=343a0a5f-b000-4199-80f2-1bb2248963e0 
fwd="75.171.228.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-08-16T01:18:01.928432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No 
web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=operation-give-
back.herokuapp.com request_id=4d62b417-c284-42f6-a43c-ec6c77335855 
fwd="75.171.228.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-08-16T01:18:02.050002+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No 
web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=operation-give-
back.herokuapp.com request_id=7c18d099-cd2e-454e-b079-bc19bf58fb30 
fwd="75.171.228.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm using Rails 5

Comment: @RockwellRice I have added some logs but am unsure if these are errors.

Comment: No those are not the errors, is there any part that you maybe see some code from your page. Also you have run "heroku run rake db:migrate" correct?  You do not have to do any rails server stuff to run that command at all.

Comment: @RockwellRice I added a different set of older logs (these actually say "error" in them). Other than these, nothing recent shows errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

This is straight from the [Heroku Error Codes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running) page.

Comment: This doesn't work. I've tried toggling between web=0 and web=1.